# Eloquent - how to add a join in the hasMany relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a typical hasMany method:

```
public function earmarks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Earmark');
}
```

But how do I add a join and some other conditions to this relationship when I use the `->with('earmarks')` to retrieve them? I want to add:

```
->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'earmarks.location')
->select('earmarks.*', 'locations.location AS em_location')
->orderBy('date', 'asc');
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more straightforward to just create a `hasOne()` relationship `location` on `earmarks`? `return $this->hasOne('location')->orderBy('date', 'ASC');`

Comment: So what would the call be from `Laptop::with('earmarks')` ... then what, to pull in the earmark location relationship?

Comment: Oh sorry, looks like it's a hasMany/belongsTo relationship between locations and earmarks. But the same applies. Just set up your relationship between earmarks and locations and you can access them the way you do any related elements.

Comment: But I still don't understand what the final call will be to get the Laptops, with the earmarks, with the location join on the earmarks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, figured out I need a closure in my `with()` clause, like this:

```
    $updated_laptops = Laptop::with([
        'earmarks' => function($q) {
            $q
            ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'earmarks.location')
            ->select('earmarks.*', 'locations.location AS em_location')
            ->orderBy('date', 'asc');
        }
    ])->addJoins()->selectListCols()->find($request->IDs)->keyBy('id');
```

Answer (score 9):

this worked for me

```
public function earmarks() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Earmark', 'labtop_id', 'id')
        ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'earmarks.location')
        ->select('earmarks.*', 'locations.location AS em_location')
        ->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();
}
```

it can be a attribute in Labtop Model and be serializable in Labtop json object like this :

```
public function GetEarmarksAttribute() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Earmark', 'labtop_id', 'id')
        ->join('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'earmarks.location')
        ->select('earmarks.*', 'locations.location AS em_location')
        ->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();
}

protected $appends = array('earmarks');
```

Comment: Good job bro. I like it

Comment: O got error on tinker:
LogicException with message 'App/User::test must return a relationship instance.' ...

Comment: when you do ->select, must remember to select the foreign_key e.g. labtop_id so laravel can map the records.

Answer (score -1):

When you defined a hasMany method in the Location model (e.g. **\App\Models\Location.php**)

```
public function earmarks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Earmark');
}
```

You can return a Location object in Controller (e.g. **LocationController.php** ):

```
public function show($id)
{
    $location = \App\Models\Location::find($id);
    return view('locations.show)
    ->with('location', $location);
}
```

Then in the view (e.g. **locations\show.blade.php**), you can retrieve the data like this:

```
@foreach ($location->earmarks->sortBy('date') as $earmark )
    <p>{{ $earmark->attribute_name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm not actually working with views, I'm just returning JSON.  `$updated_laptops = Laptop::with('earmarks')->addJoins()->selectListCols()->find($request->IDs)->keyBy('id');`  -- this code does what I need EXCEPT I need the earmarks to also get the Location. So almost something like `Laptop::with('earmarks')->with('location.location')` -- although I presume this would get the relation to laptops, not to earmarks.