# Laravel9 how to access Model relation in blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables, one of invoices one with coletes and one with incasaris.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Mail;
Use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
Use App\Models\Incasari;
Use App\Models\colete;


class Invoice extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

   public function incasari(){
    return $this->hasMany(Incasari::class,'i_plati_id','id') 
    ->selectRaw('incasaris.i_plati_id,SUM(incasaris.i_totaleuro) as totalincasat') 
    ->groupBy('i_plati_id');
}


   
public function colete(){
    return $this->hasMany(colete::class,'invoice_id','id') 
    ->selectRaw('coletes.invoice_id,SUM(coletes.totaleuro) as totaleuro') 
    ->groupBy('invoice_id');
}


}
```

In my controller the following function:

```
$invoices = Invoice::with(['colete','incasari'])->get();
```

returns me the data I want when I use DB($invoices)

However, when I want to access the relation in my blade view as:

```
@foreach ($invoices as $invoice )
                                                     
                                                                                                 
                          <tr>
                             <td> {{$invoice->id}} </td>
                             <td> {{$invoice->serieId}} </td>
                             <td> {{$invoice->colete->invoice_id}}  </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
```

It returns:

```
Property [invoice_id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

But, If I use :

```
 @foreach ($invoices as $invoice )
                                                         
                                                                                                     
                              <tr>
                                 <td> {{$invoice->id}} </td>
                                 <td> {{$invoice->serieId}} </td>
                                 <td> {{$invoice->colete}}  </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
```

It returns me the data as:

```
[{"invoice_id":2008,"totaleuro":"3000.00"}]
```

I am pretty sure this is a syntax error but because I am new to Eloquent I can't really figure it out where

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what $invoice->colete returns? It will likely be a collection which means you will have to loop over them as well and can't just access a Model property on it.

Changing to:

```
 @foreach ($invoices as $invoice )
                                                        
<tr>
   <td> {{$invoice->id}} </td>
   <td> {{$invoice->serieId}} </td>
   <td> 
    @foreach($invoice->colete as $colete)
     {{$colete->invoice_id}}  <br/>
    @endforeach
   </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: But as one more question, is there any way I could join the relations in the invoice query in order to have only one query?

Comment: @Catalin-Gabriel You can find more info on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749148/eloquent-how-to-add-a-join-in-the-hasmany-relationship